# Using EJBs only for interceptors

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, interceptor, java-ee-7

I want to know if using an EJB only to make use of the interceptors is a good idea or not?

I have turned off the transaction management by using `@TransactionAttribute(NEVER)` so that it wont have any transaction management capabilities which is not required.

I know that this can be done in Spring. But I still would like to know if my idea is good.

If this is a bad idea, can anyone please tell me how to do this using APIs which are part of JEE spec. If this cannot be done using any JEE APIs then I would not mind using Spring.

BTW, I need interceptors because there is so much of logging code in my application. Each time a request comes I have to persist a record in a table and plus there are other stuffs.

P.S.

I am new to EJBs. I know with EJB we get features such as transaction management and interceptors.

I have an application where the services are exposed as REST and SOAP web services. We have plans to also expose the services as remote services using remote EJBs.

We have some logging code written in each service. The logging code will basically log the details in a table before the method is returned. Also we have some services which calls some 3pp web services. We will log these details in another table. The logging code is written in each and every service method.

So I came up with an idea of introducing interceptors and moving the logging code to appropriate interceptors. Initially I have introduced the interceptors on couple of methods. The code is working fine and now I would like to rewrite all my services to use these interceptors.

Now I am think if it is a good idea to use EJBs only for intercepting the methods. I do not want to use any other EJB feature other than interceptors. So I turned off transaction management with `@TransactionAttribute(NEVER)`. My class will look something like below

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class StudentServiceBean {

    @ReportingInterceptor
    public Student getStudent(String id) {
    }
}

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class StudentBackendBean {

    @BackendInterceptor
    public Student getStudent(String id) {
    }
}
```

Below are my questions

1. Is there any thing else I should consider beside turning of
   transaction management?
2. Is it a good idea to use EJBs only to take
   advantage of interceptors?
3. Since our application contains 100s of
   services, how will the application scale? (I know scaling is based
   on the resources available)

I cannot use filters because we have plans to expose our services as remote ejbs. Since a filter cannot intercept remote ejb calls I do not want to use filters.

Comment: Can anyone please shed some light here?

Comment: Can anyone please shed some light?

Comment: If I understand well, you want to make a log layer using EJBs. AFAIK, Interceptors are able to intercept EJBs (e.g. Session Beans and Message-Driven Beans), so I don't understand what you mean with "ejb only to make use of the interceptors". Can you provide some more details?

Comment: Considering this part "BTW, I need interceptors because there is so much of logging code in my application. Each time a request comes I have to persist a record in a table and plus there are other stuffs." You can achieve that using Servlet Filters or JSF Phase Listeners.

Comment: @Jaumzera I updated my question. Hope the explanation/details help.

Comment: Have you tried CDI beans? That would basically consist of changing `@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)` to `@RequestScoped` (or any other CDI scope) and making sure you obtain your bean with @Inject (probably you are already doing that with EJBs).

Comment: @marcus i never knew that we can take advantage of interceptors with `@RequestScoped` annotation. I just replaced the Stateless annotation with RequestScoped and the interceptor is still invoked. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Basically, annotating your class with `@Stateless` you've already made it an EJB. So, in this case, I don't see any problem in using Interceptor to do the job you mentioned. To say the truth, Interceptors were made exactly to do this kind of job.

About your questions:

> Is there any thing else I should consider beside turning of transaction management?

No. If you keep using `@Stateless` beans as services. Keep on mind that you're not disabling transactions, with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)` you are just telling that beans doesn't support TX. But in your case, it's ok.

> Is it a good idea to use EJBs only to take advantage of interceptors?

Well, be careful. If you won't use the advantages of the Java EE platform, I think a small set of configuration would be enough for you. Take a look on this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html.

> Since our application contains 100s of services, how will the application scale? (I know scaling is based on the resources available).

I don't see any problem in having something around 100 services in a enterprise application. But I'd consider to part it in some minors applications deployed separately.